# How to identify a request's crucial information that needs to be sent?

Tags: web-scraping, session-cookies, scrapy

I wanted to scrape some fares from [this website](https://www.cabforce.com/) which uses requests for autocompletion.

This is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
import urllib

class CabforceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cabforce'
    start_urls = ['https://www.cabforce.com']
    complete_url = 'https://www.cabforce.com/v1/geo/autocomplete'

    def parse(self, response):
        payload = {
            'chnl': 'cforce',
            'complete': 'Barcelona Airport',
            'destination': 'Barcelona'
        }
        return Request(
            self.complete_url,
            self.print_json,
            method='POST',
            body=urllib.urlencode(payload),
            headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

    def print_json(self, response):
        print response.body
```

Unfortunately my response looks like this:

```
{"status":"ArgumentError","reason":"Cannot validate input","description":null,"reasonType":2000,"details":[]}
```

How do I find out what information is missing but needs to be sent with the request? I thought about the JSESSIONID and version but I couldn't figure out how to do that.
Thanks for any hints and have a lovely day!

Comment: Have you tried using the network tab of google chrome's developer tools to reverse engineer the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not even need the cookies to send with your request. The problem is with

```
body=urllib.urlencode(payload),
```

This encodes the body to URL-Format however if you look at the body of the request of your browser you will see that a JSON is the body.

So the solution is to `import json` and to change the line mentioned above to this one:

```
body=json.dumps(payload),
```

In this case I get  the following result back with your spider:

```
{"status":"Ok","result":{"autocomplete":{"elements":[{"type":16,"description":"(BCN) - Barcelona Airport, Barcelona, Spain","location":{"lat":41.289545,"lng":2.072639},"raw":{"name":"(BCN) - Barcelona Airport","city":"Barcelona","country":"Spain"}},{"location":{"lat":41.3181887517739,"lng":2.07441323388724},"description":"Barcelona Airport Hotel, Plaza Volatería, 3, El Prat de Llobregat, Spain","raw":{"name":"Barcelona Airport Hotel","city":"El Prat de Llobregat","country":"Spain"},"type":4},{"location":{"lat":41.3176275,"lng":2.0249774},"description":"Airport Barcelona Apartments, Rafael Casanova, 37, Viladecans, Spain","raw":{"name":"Airport Barcelona Apartments","city":"Viladecans","country":"Spain"},"type":4}]}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are hidden inputs in the form with data that you are not submitting. Use a `FormRequest` object instead of a simple `Request`. This request will populate all the fields automatically and you can override only those that you want to change.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin).